# Trying to update multiple rows in a gridview, keep getting the error 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string, sql-update

I've seen this question asked a lot but the answers I've found seem out of date for my version of VWD because it calls them 'obsolete'.  I am just in school and I am very new to this.  I am trying to update a value for every line in a gridview that is checked.  The first checked value always gets updated but the second, third, etc. never work because the connectionstring property has not been initialized.  These are the namespaces I have used:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

This is the code that makes me run into problems (it is inside of a button click method).  The error seems to come the second time it runs through the 'try' statement and tries to open the connection:

```
    string NewASNConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Order"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection ShipConnection = new
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Order"].ToString());

    string insertSQL = "INSERT INTO [TRUCKS] ([DateSent]) VALUES (@DateSent)";
    SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, ShipConnection);
    InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateSent", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
    Int32 ASNNumber = GetASN();      

    foreach (GridViewRow grvRows in  grvShipPallets.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)grvRows.FindControl("chkShip")).Checked)
        {

            string RFID = Convert.ToString(grvRows.Cells[1].Text);

            SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE PALLETS SET TRUCKS$ASNNumber=@ASNNumber WHERE RFID=@RFID", ShipConnection);
            UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ASNNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ASNNumber;
            UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@RFID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= RFID;
            ShipConnection.Open();
            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ShipConnection.Close();

            int InsertChecker = -2;
            try
            {
                ShipConnection.Open();
                InsertChecker = UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
                lblASNConfirmation.Text = "You have shipped the selected Order(s) on ASN # " + ASNNumber;
            }
            catch (Exception MyError)
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "There has been an error with the database. <br/>";
                lblError.Text += MyError.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                ShipConnection.Dispose();
                ShipConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    grvShipPallets.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using more than one connection to talk to the same database? Just create one connection outside of the for loop and use that for all your db operations.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to only one connection now.  The connection starts outside of the loop, but I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string NewASNConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Order"].ConnectionString;
```

and

```
SqlConnection ShipConnection = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Order"].ConnectionString);
```

instead of

```
string NewASNConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Order"].ToString();
```

and

```
SqlConnection ShipConnection = 
       new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Order"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your disposing the object in your finally statement.  So in subsequent loops your connection no longer exists as an object.  Remove the dispose line.  Closing the connection is sufficient.  Don't dispose of it until you no longer need it.

Comment: A for what it's worth... you would dispose after you close.  You can't close an object that no longer exists.